# Response contains a circular reference and cannot be serialized to JSON in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, claudia.js

I am developing a API with AWS. I am using Claudia API Builder.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

const createOrder = async (order) => {
    if(!order || !order.id || !order.address ) 
    throw new Error ('To order a pizza you must send a id and the adress of the customer')

    return await docClient.put({
        TableName: 'pizza-order',
        Item: {
            orderId : order.id,
            pizza: order.pizza,
            address: order.address,
            status: 'pending',
        }
    })
}

module.exports = createOrder;
```

Then I send request using postman

```
{
    "pizza": 1,
    "address": "Bangladesh",
    "id": 2
}
```

But It return a Error like THis:

`{ "errorMessage": "Response contains a circular reference and cannot be serialized to JSON" }`

Any solution!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add the `.promise` method:

```
return await docClient.put({
    TableName: 'pizza-order',
    Item: {
        orderId : order.id,
        pizza: order.pizza,
        address: order.address,
        status: 'pending',
    }
}).promise().   <== here
```

Comment: Thanx for the solution. I am reading a book on aws which is using claudia API builder. But I find SAM more useful. What's your thought on moving to SAM and also sorry for the theoretical comments.

Comment: This was also helpful for the SQS module.

 let response = await clientQueue.getQueueAttributes(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err)
            }
            else {
                console.log(data)
            }
        }).promise()